# Using a Makefile for Debain packages

Tags: makefile, debian

I'm trying to put together a Makefile that will create a folder and clone repositories from GIT

I'm having trouble putting it all together so I'm starting with a generic Makefile

My makefile:

```
$(shell mkdir -p myDir)
$(shell git.sh)
```

The shell script that I am trying to get to invoke

```
#!/bin/sh  
REPOSRC="my bitbucket repo URL"
LOCALREPO="myDir"

# We do it this way so that we can abstract if from just git later on
LOCALREPO_VC_DIR=$LOCALREPO/.git

if [ ! -d $LOCALREPO_VC_DIR ]
then
    git clone $REPOSRC $LOCALREPO
else
    cd $LOCALREPO
    git pull $REPOSRC
fi

# End
```

When I run make I'm getting the following error:

```
Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Also, is this the correct way to go about this task?

Comment: So far, your question says nothing about Debian packages, consider removing `debian` tag

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what make is useful for. The task you describe ("create a folder and clone repositorie") will not benefit at all from using make (although this can - of course- be done by a makefile).

Comment: Your makefile has no target ! No wonder it fails...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is not a makefile.  It's really a shell script written in makefile syntax (and, as you've discovered from the errors, not correct makefile syntax).

Make is a tool that allows commands to be run to update a set of target files, or not run if any of the target files don't need to be updated, based on comparing timestamps of the target files and their prerequisite files.  These dependency relationships can be chained.

That's *all* that make is for.

To prototypical example is compiling a program: if any of the source files have been modified then you need to recompile the object files for those sources; if object files are updated then libraries might need to be re-created; if object or library files are updated then programs might need to be re-linked.

If your problem space doesn't map, or can't be made to map, to that mechanism, then make and makefiles are not the correct tool for the job you have in mind.  Based on your description of your problem, make is not the right tool for this job.

You should just write a shell script, as you've basically done here already, and move forward.

If you do want to write a makefile you should spend some time understanding the syntax of makefiles and how they work, rather than just searching on Stack Overflow and trying to put together a makefile based on the answers.  For example, try reading at least the introduction of the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

With `$(shell ...)` construct you substitute shell command output into the makefile. Of course after calling `mkdir` or invoking git the output is not a valid makefile.

Your makefile should be like this

```
all:
    mkdir -p myDir
    ./git.sh
```

note that indentation after `all:` *has* to be done with tabs.

And it looks like you don't need `make` for your task. Just shell script would be enough.